# how to get the first splited part of each index in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

we have an array like below, length of the array is not constant(may increase/decrease).

```
[255028AD_ABC_DE_2057,261830AD_ABC_FG_2876,.......]
```

My aim is to achieve only the first part of each index like below.

```
[255028AD,261830AD,.........]
```

Please help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and attempt to do the work. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: you need to consider that your array must contains strings, `['255028AD_ABC_DE_2057','261830AD_ABC_FG_2876',...]`

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```js
var arr = ['255028AD_ABC_DE_2057', '261830AD_ABC_FG_2876'];
arr = arr.map(el => el.split('_')[0]);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

With `Array.map()` and `String.substr()` functions:

```js
var arr = ['255028AD_ABC_DE_2057', '261830AD_ABC_FG_2876' ],
    result = arr.map(v => v.substr(0, v.indexOf('_')));
console.log(result);
```

- `v.indexOf('_')` - to find the 1st position of `_` char
- `v.substr(0, v.indexOf('_'))` - extracting the substring starting from the position `0` to the 1st position of `_` char (getting slice)

Answer (score 0):

You could match the first non underscore characters and return the first item of the matching result.

```js
var array = ['255028AD_ABC_DE_2057', '261830AD_ABC_FG_2876'],
    result = array.map(s => s.match(/^[^_]+/)[0]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should work:

```
const arr = ['255028AD_ABC_DE_2057','261830AD_ABC_FG_2876'];
const arrModified = arr.map(element => 
    element.substr(0, element.indexOf('_')));
console.log(arrModified)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Array.map function so your code will look something like this

```
[].map(item => item.split('_')[0])
```

where `[]` is your array

in ES5 syntax it will look like

```
[].map(function(item) {
  return item.split('_')[0];
})
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Just use map https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/map

with

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/split

like

```
var array = ["12_bla","13_ble"].map(function (el) { return el.split('_',1)[0]; });
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a `for ... of`:

```js
var arr = ['255028AD_ABC_DE_2057', '261830AD_ABC_FG_2876'];
var index = 0;
for (item of arr) {
  arr[index] = item.split('_')[0];
  index++;
}

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also do like

```js
var result = ["255028AD_ABC_DE_2057","261830AD_ABC_FG_2876"].map(s => s.replace(/_.*/,""));
console.log(result);
```